# How to enable CentOS ssh client?

Tags: centos, ssh

I have a CentOS server and a computer running Linux Mint on my home network. The computer is running an SSH server on it that works when I connect to it from any other computer, however I am unable to connect to it from my server, it just hangs and never connects, no error messages. The problem must lie therefore in the servers ssh client but I can't figure out what the issue is. I have opened all necessary ports in my server firewall and I am able to ping the computer from the server however an nmap host discovery scan shows me that there are no hosts up on the entire IP range.

Comment: This sounds more like a networking issue than a problem with your ssh client.

Comment: I can connect to the computer from other computers just fine. I used to run a different OS on the server and it worked just fine too. This has to be a server issue.

Comment: *"I have opened all necessary ports in my server firewall"* I doubt that.

Comment: I have enabled the ssh service in firewall-cmd and I am able to ssh into the server, I just can't ssh from the server into another computer.

Comment: The question is remarkably devoid of data showing debugging attempts/detail.  Perhaps attempt ssh with debugging on (i.e. ssh -v/ssh -vv/ssh -vvv) or look for ssh errors using journalctl -xe, or perhaps `sestatus` to see if SELinux is in the mix and then report back with more detail.  Something like audit2allow may be useful if SELinux is enforcing.  Proving the firewall isn't blocking is important (i.e. /etc/firewalld/firewalld.conf -> LogDenied=all and restart firewalld then look for blocked traffic).  Proving blocks don't happen on both ends is important.  Are you using passwords or keys?

Comment: Compare/contrast detail in this question:  https://serverfault.com/questions/699347/incoming-ssh-works-but-all-outgoing-fails